# Inline Assignment as a way to ensure read orderings

Tags: java, micro-optimization, java-memory-model, fork-join

In the `ForkJoinPool` class in Java7, there is a comment regarding the implementation which states:

> Methods signalWork() and scan() are the main bottlenecks so are especially heavily micro-optimized/mangled.  There are lots of **inline assignments** (of form "while ((local = field) != 0)") which are usually the simplest way to ensure the required read orderings (which are sometimes critical)

My question is: how does inline assignment help with read-ordering (i'm familiar with the Java Memory model and i can't see how inline assignment helps here)?

Comment: `while ((local = field) != 0){...}` is certainly simpler than `local = field; while (local != 0) {...; local = field }`, and `while (field !=0) {... read field; ...  }` obviously doesn't ensure the required read ordering (i.e. read `field` once per loop, then access its "fields"). At least that's how I interpret your quoted paragraph.

Comment: I'm not arguing over simplicity. I'm interested in what read-ordering problem may arise from your first example( local = field; while (local != 0) {...; local = field }). I can see the problems in your second example of course.

Comment: of course the first example doesn't have problems, it's only a non "simplest way to ensure the required read orderings", as opposed to inline assignments (which is simpler).

Comment: So, there is actually nothing "micro-optimized/mangled" about these inline assignments. I guess that these terms got me thinking there's something i miss here.

Comment: Well,the fact that `cnt` in `signalWork()` contains several fields accessed via bitmasks and is read only once via that assignment could be considered micro-optimization/mangling.

Answer (score 1):

I think ninjalj is right in that the expression could safely be rewritten as `local = field; while (local != 0) {...; local = field }`. However, in the actual code, they have much more complex expressions, for example: `while ((((e = (int)(c = ctl)) | (u = (int)(c >>> 32))) & (INT_SIGN|SHORT_SIGN)) == (INT_SIGN|SHORT_SIGN) && e >= 0) {` . Rewriting **that** into a series of temporary variable assignments and conditionals would change it from two lines to half a screen of code, and having two copies of such non-trivial code code (before the loop and inside loop body) would be a maintainability and readability nightmare.

Code size and number of temporary local variables in the whole function might also grow, which could impact performance or at least make the optimizer's work harder. The inlined version can be compiled to: `label loop_start; calculate condition; if (!condition) goto after_loop; loop_body; goto loop_start; label after_loop;` while I doubt the compiler would always be smart enough to deduplicate by itself the code where loop condition is explicitly calculated twice.

Answer (score 1):

In theory in-lining should make no difference to ordering. The compiler is free to re-order your code, same goes for the JIT compiler and in some cases the CPU.

Having read the code in question you should pay attention to the fact that many of the fields read in the said while loops are **volatile**. Volatile reads and writes cannot be re-ordered and are subject to happens-before relationships. See this [blog post](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) for an excellent explanation of volatile semantics.

By in-lining the volatile reads the rest of the conditions in are subject to visibility rules and are not eligible for re-ordering. This may well have been awkward to achieve by other means.